# Setar variável com SELECT e WITH no SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou tentando setar a variável com uma consulta, O select só dá certo dessa maneira utilizando o WITH, porém ele está dando erro quando eu vou atribuir o valor na variável.

O código que estou tentando:

```
  DECLARE @contador INT, @empresas INT, @id_empresa INT
  SET @contador = 1
  SET @empresas = (SELECT COUNT(ID_Pessoa) FROM Empresa)


  WHILE (@contador <= @empresas)
  BEGIN

  SET @id_empresa = with CTE_R as
  (SELECT e.ID_Pessoa, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID_Pessoa) as RowNum FROM                         Empresa e (NOLOCK)) 
  select ID_Pessoa from CTE_R where RowNum = 1

  INSERT INTO Produto_Lista_Empresa (ID_Produto_Lista, ID_Empresa)
  SELECT ID, @id_empresa FROM Produto_Lista

  SET @contador = @contador + 1
  CONTINUE;
  END
```

Ele está dando erro na hora de atribuir o valor da variavel @id_empresa

Comment: Onde está dando o erro e qual erro que aparece?

Comment: está dando erro na hora de atribuir valor a variável @id_empresa, o erro é: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WITH CTE_R AS (
  SELECT e.ID_Pessoa,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID_Pessoa) AS RowNum
    FROM Empresa e WITH(NOLOCK)
)
SELECT @id_empresa = ID_Pessoa
  FROM CTE_R
 WHERE RowNum = 1
```

Mas na realidade você tem outra forma de conseguir esse valor:

```
SELECT TOP 1 @id_empresa = e.ID_Pessoa
  FROM Empresa e WITH(NOLOCK)
 ORDER BY ID_Pessoa
```

**Observação:** Sua lógica parece um tanto equivocada. A melhor forma de fazer essa inserção não seria um `LOOP`. Você pode conseguir o mesmo resultado com o seguinte `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO produto_lista_empresa(id_produto_lista,
                                  id_empresa)
SELECT pl.id,
       e.id_pessoa
  FROM empresa e
 CROSS JOIN produto_lista pl
```